# VBA While Loop Trouble (Should be easy fix)

Tags: vba, excel

```
 While ActiveCell.Value <> "Console Foreman"
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
 End While
```

For some reason I'm getting a syntax error for "End While". I have no idea why. The purpose of the While loop is to go down by one cell every iteration and check to see if the cell contains the string "Console Foreman", if it encounters that string I want to break the loop. This is my first While loop I've made in VBA and I assume I'm just making a silly error, although after trying different things, still cant figure it out.

Thanks for helping out a n00b ;)

Comment: change `End While` to `Wend`

Comment: Having that done, please see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264682.aspx

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks so much, and if you dont mind me asking, why would I avoid using Select?

Comment: @LiCarroll Because, as you can read in the beginning of the second answer there, ["1) It slows down your code. 2) It is usually the main cause of runtime errors."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/11683).